# AngularJS UI-Router scroll to top after state change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

My page should scroll to top again after i change the page.
I have an angular1.6 page with page transitions & ui-router, so i cant use `<div ui-view="main" autoscroll="true"></div>`. I tried the following code but its not even executing the console.log :/ :

```
 angular.module("App", ["ngAnimate", "ui.router", "vcRecaptcha"]).run(["$rootScope", "$state", function(a, b) {
        a.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',function(){ 
            window.scrollTo(0,0);
            console.log("foo");
        })

    }])
```

I tried routeChangeSuccess too ... any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I use this and it works `$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
            $window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        });`.

Comment: :/ not working unfortunately

Comment: If you don't see the `console.log()` I think the problem is somewhere else - probably in your routing. I'm sure that routing is in module `'ngRoute'` and not `'ui.router'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the new ui-router (v1.0.0), the $stateChange* events will not work. You must use $transitions.on* hooks from now on.

Comment: i need a timeout because of my transitions, its scrolling to the top too quick. any ideas?

Comment: I don't sorry, but i going to look for it

Comment: The callback is a traditional function you can set your timeout

Comment: Your welcome, excuse me i was looking for scrolling to top nicely, i found this http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/animated-scroll-to-top, and i was analysing the code. I'm glad you could find the answer

Comment: I dindn't understand very well ^^ . this is what i understand: you can use a function in "to" and "from", like this ... match = {
  to: function(state) {
    return state.data != null && state.data.authRequired === true;
  }
}